# Running a batch file as a system service in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, batch

I currently have a batch file used to start a voice server application in C:\Teamspeak. The application cannot start directly because the batch file passes settings to the application. Is it possible to have this batch file start the voice server every time the server is started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Task Scheduler to run anything you want at system startup.

Answer (score 1):

How To Create a User-Defined Service

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

See these questions.

- [Help with running an application as a service on Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/55607/help-with-running-an-application-as-a-service-on-server-2008)
- [Looking for a solution to allow a regular app to run as a service](https://serverfault.com/questions/75292/looking-for-a-solution-to-allow-a-regular-app-to-run-as-a-service)
- [install service in windows server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/58025/install-service-in-windows-server-2008)
- [How to create a windows service in XP](https://serverfault.com/questions/12094/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-xp)

Create a schedule task that runs at boot

- http://www.myboogpages.com/2009/02/how-to-create-a-scheduled-task-that-runs-at-boot-time.html